# Как работают UID и GID в Linux?

Tags: android, linux, users

Чисто теоретический вопрос: как *на уровне ядра* работают UID и GID в Linux?

Смотрите, в чем проблема. С одной стороны, в штатных дистрибутивах Linux и даже в BSD (насчёт macOS и iOS я не знаю, не юзал и не интересовался) "пользовательская система" устроена таким образом. Идентификация пользователей и вообще их существование определяется в `/etc/passwd`, групп - в `/etc/group`. Т е, в системе есть такая запись:

```
root@linux: ~ # cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/bin/sh
user:x:1000:1000:usergrp:/bin/sh
root@linux: ~ # cat /etc/group
root:x:0:root
sudo:x:27:root,user
root@linux: ~ # id
uid=0(root), gid=0(root), groups=27(sudo)
```

В Android же совершенно иная схема. Файлов `/etc/passwd` и `/etc/group` нету, да и в целом UID и GID там определяются иным образом. Но отсюда вывод, что как-то можно переопределить процесс создания и опознания пользователя. И вот вопрос: как же это устроено?

Причём, если даже в Android запустить штатный дистрибутив, то вот что получается:

```
(chroot) root@linux: ~ # useradd user
(chroot) root@linux: ~ # su user -l
(chroot) user@linux: ~ $ id
uid=1000000(user), gid=1000000(user)
```

И вот вопрос: а как в системах Linux (в т ч Android) "закладывается" "определение" UID и GID? Как переопределяется в Android создание и идентификация Linux-пользователя? Где это прописывается и указывается в системе или это определённым образом программируется в ядре?? Хотя, честно, я не раз собирал ядра Linux (в т ч для Android) и соответствующих пунктов не находил...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list

Comment: Ну, система ACL есть и в штатных дистрибутивах, только причём тут она, я не совсем понимаю? (Или это у меня с английским плохо)

Comment: Исправляю: да, поддержку acl и user_xattr можно включить по умолчанию через `tune2fs`

Comment: Да и ACL вроде бы для все той же идентификации юзеров надо необходимые файлы, не?

Comment: passwd и group — это ни на что не влияющие файлики с информацией просто для удобства, а UID и GID — это всего лишь числа, которые могут быть абсолютно любыми. Например, sudo с опцией runas_allow_unknown_id позволяет перейти в пользователя с произвольными UID и GID `sudo -u \#8800 -g \#5553535 -i`

Comment: Хорошо, но как тогда даже штатный дистрибутив "прогибается" под Android? В штатных дистрибутивах заложено добавлять пользователей начиная с ID 1000, но в Android то же самое - с ID 60000. Да, я читал, что это захардкожено в bionic и zygote, но вот Linux-овый useradd работает из chroot-а, ему по барабану, что там прописано в bionic.

Comment: А вы уверены, что он действительно штатный? Я не в курсе, что конкретно вы используете и как установили, но наберусь наглости предположить, что кто-то уже успел пропатчить дистрибутив под особенности андроида

Comment: А, я тогда брал Devuan4, ставил через Linux Deploy. В нем есть, насколько мне известно, куча специфических для Android-а патчей (в т ч для работы фреймбуфера и поддержки Android UserID). Поставил Alpine Linux (скачал rootfs с сайта, а не через Linux Deploy) - все работает в точности как в штатных дистрибутивах.

Comment: UPD: разобрался. Есть файл `/etc/login.defs`, туда пишется специфика добавления нового пользователя. В т ч там можно настроить "dynamically allocated users" (по сути, Android-овских пользователей)

Comment: Плюс, есть ещё такая фича, как **system account** (и это в штатных-то дистрибутивах). Крч, я разобрался и понял, как это работает)